# Apache Basic authentication using .htaccess file doesnt work on files in directory

Tags: security, web-server, apache2, http-basic-authentication

I need to protect files within a directory, I used .htaccess file as below and put it in the directory :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "c:\passwords\.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

It works fine when I browse the directory example.come/directory, but it doesn't work when I browse example.come/directory/aFile.zip. It doesn't ask for user and password.

How can I protect files in the directory?

Comment: If you entered your credentials when visiting example.come/directory then your browser won't ask again if you visit example.come/directory/aFile.zip, it uses the cached credentials.

Comment: @wurtel I tested example.com/directory/aFile.zip with another browser.